# When two classes implement the same interface

Tags: java, interface

Suppose there are 2 classes which implement a same interface and the methods from that interface. If I call a method directly from the interface, what is what decides which implementation will be returned (from first or second class) ?

Comment: Well, you can always write a sample code and see it yourself.

Comment: I am at work. I dont have time. :D i thought someone can say a general rule

Comment: What do you mean. How would you instantiate the interface unless you specify the concrete class?

Comment: @Madrugada: "I dont have time" is *never* a good enough reason not to do your own research.

Comment: I think it is a good question. It is true that "I do not have time" is not an acceptable reason but the question is valid and useful. I do not understand why questions like this just get - - -

Answer (score 10):

```
package test;
    public interface InterfaceX {
    int doubleInt(int i);
}

package test;
public class ClassA implements InterfaceX{
    @Override
    public int doubleInt(int i) {
        return i+i;
    }
}

package test;
public class ClassB implements InterfaceX{
    @Override
    public int doubleInt(int i) {
        return 2*i;
    }
}

package test;
public class TestInterface {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new TestInterface();
    }
    public TestInterface() {
        InterfaceX i1 = new ClassA();
        InterfaceX i2 = new ClassB();
        System.out.println("i1 is class "+i1.getClass().getName());
        System.out.println("i2 is class "+i2.getClass().getName());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You don't call a method directly from an interface, you call it on a reference that points to an instance of a class.  Whichever class that is determines which method gets called.

Comment: At least that you define an [anonymous class](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_12.htm).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't know what you mean. You still create instances of anonymous classes and call methods on those objects.

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant that you can create an anonymous class in order to define a new implementation of the interface regarding any of the actual classes that implemented it.

Answer (score 2):

You define the instance of an interface by executing the constructor of a concrete class that implements the interface.

```
Interface interface = new ConcreteClass();
```

Answer (score -1):

interface cannot have body/definition for the method. All the methods are abstract. You cannot define method body, hence you cannot call any method from interface.